# Sincronizando usuário LDAP usando SAML

Tags: active-directory

Implementei a autenticação do produto utilizando SAML. Este produto tem uma rotina de sincronização de usuário com o Active Directory. Alguém sabe se podem ocorrer problemas em disparar a sincronização utilizando o SAML, visto que o Identity Provider estará em outro domínio acessado pela Web ?